# How can I catch the jQTouch animation completion?

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I use jQTouch (and its built-in animations) in developing iPhone version of a website. So, I have a static menu:

```
<ul class="rounded">
  <li class="arrow"><a href="#item1" class="fade">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="arrow"><a href="#item2" class="fade">Item 2</a></li>
   <li class="arrow"><a href="#item3" class="fade">Item 3</a></li>
   <li class="arrow"><a href="#item4" class="fade">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

that's included in some `div`'s. My problem is to hide the item that has link with hash same as the `id` of the `div`, it belongs to, and same as the `location.hash`, when the user is on such a page.

So, `click` event on a link (which moves user to another `div` with animation) isn't appropriate because the `location.hash` changes only when the animation completes.

That's the question: How can I catch the jQTouch animation completion to solve the problem? Maybe I can do it with jQuery itself, but how?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've found the solution. So, I post it here.

```
  $('body > div').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(){

    //wait a bit for the end of the animation
    //and hash change
    setTimeout(function(){

        //current div id
        divId = '#' + $('.current .toolbar + .section').parent().attr('id');

        //test whether there's a link to the same page
        link = $(divId + ' .rounded li').find('a[href='+divId+']');

        if (   divId == location.hash      
            && link.length > 0 )
        {
            $('a[href='+divId+']').parent().fadeOut(0);
        }
        else
        {
            $('a[href='+divId+']').parent().fadeIn(0);
        }
      }, 100);              
  });
```

Comment: Ha-ha! It's so called 'just google it!'... People, paste into the google 'jqtouch events', and the very the first link will pass you to the google repository's wiki about jQTouch Callback Events, http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/CallbackEvents.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on Safari and Chrome?
For me it only works on Firefox.

Comment: I haven't been done something with it a long time. As far as I remember, it works appropriately only in Webkit. Because jQTouch is designed for Apple's mobile development. We stopped exploring the mobile development at the time and now I'm waiting for jQuery Mobile. It's true cross-platform thing as they promise.